# Why are Arduino timer registers not 0?

Tags: timers, avr

I'm trying to use the timer registers to do some timing on my Arduino Mega 2560.

The output of the following code confuses me:

```
void setup ()
{
    // Set up serial connection
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial) {}

    // Print control registers of timer 1
    Serial.println(TCCR1A); // Outputs 1
    Serial.println(TCCR1B); // Outputs 3
}

void loop () {}
```

Why is `TCCR1A` equal to `1` and `TCCR1B` equal to `3`? The documentation of the chip says the initial values of the registers are zero. I could of course set them to zero, but I want to understand why it works like this. The values are the same for the other 16-bit timers (3, 4 and 5).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Arduino core does things at startup. One of those things is to configure the timers ready for PWM operation.

Here's the relevant bits from `init()` in `wiring.c`:

```
    // set timer 1 prescale factor to 64
    sbi(TCCR1B, CS11);
#if F_CPU >= 8000000L
    sbi(TCCR1B, CS10);
#endif

#if defined(TCCR1A) && defined(WGM10)
    sbi(TCCR1A, WGM10);
#endif
```